# Neighborhoods of the hyperdiagonal in a product space

Tags: gn.general-topology

We recently need the following result about product space in an applied analysis paper:

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space, and $\bigotimes^{k+1}M = \overbrace{M \times M \times \dots \times M}^{(k+1)-{\rm times}}$ be equipped with the product topology.
Let $U \subset \bigotimes^{k+1}M$ be a neighborhood of the hyperdiagonal
$ \{ (x,x,\dots,x) : x\in M\}$. When $k\geq 2$, there is a smaller open neighborhood
$V' \subset U$ of the hyperdiagonal
of the form
$
V' = \{(x_0,x_1,\dots,x_k) \,:\, (x_i,x_{i+1}) \in V \,, 0 \leq i < k\}
$
for $V \subset M \times M$  an open neighborhood of the diagonal of $M\times M$.

The proof (see Appendix B of http://www.math.drexel.edu/~tyu/Papers/SE7.pdf) relies on a metric; we wondered if any form of this result is written down somewhere, and if the metrizability of the space $M$ is required for the result to hold true. Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with uniformities? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space). I haven't thought about the details or read your proof yet, but this looks like the sort of thing that, if true for metric spaces, should also be true for uniform spaces. A topological space is "uniformizable" if and only if it is completely regular, so my guess is that your result is true for all completely regular spaces.

Comment: Thanks. My coauthor, Tom Duchamp, shared the same conjecture with me also, and he wondered if the result is wrong for a general topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result does not hold for general topological spaces.

For a counterexample, equip $M = \{a, b, c\}$ with the topology whose open sets are $\emptyset$, $M$, $\{a, b\}$, $\{b\}$ and $\{b, c\}$. 
The set $U= \{a,b\}^3\cup \{b,c\}^3\subseteq M^3$ is an open neighborhood of the ternary diagonal.

Now let $V\subseteq M^2$ be any open neighborhood of the binary diagonal. Since (i) $V$ contains $(a,a)$, (ii) $V$ is open in the product topology, and (iii) $\{a,b\}$ is the smallest open set of $M$ containing $a$, it follows that $\{a,b\}^2\subseteq V$. Similarly $\{b,c\}^2\subseteq V$. But now $V$ is already too big for our purposes. If $V'$ is defined to be
$\{(x_0,x_1,x_2) \,:\, (x_i,x_{i+1}) \in V \,, 0 \leq i \lt 2\},
$
then $(a,b,c)\in V'-U$. That is, there is no neighborhood $V$ of the binary diagonal that induces a neighborhood $V'$ of the ternary diagonal such that $V'\subseteq U$.